# How to pass multiple scopes to Mixer's OAuth /authorize API?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, mixer

I use the following to call Mixer's OAuth authorize API

```
https://mixer.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2Flocalhost&state=abc123&scope=chat:connect,chat:chat
```

then I get the following error message

```
Error details for developers: The following permissions are invalid: chat:connect,chat:chat.
```

If I include only one scope then it works.

How do I send two scopes?

Answer (score 1):

Discovered that I simply need to replace the comma `,` to a space

```
&scope=chat:connect chat:chat
```